# Meteor.user() is not showing custom fields on the client

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am adding custom fields for my user on account creation, publishing the fields, and subscribing to that publication, and yet my `Meteor.user().customField` will not be accessible at the client side.

So in my `imports/api/users/users.js` I add the following snippet:

```
import { Random } from 'meteor/random'
Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => {
    const cond = assignUserCondition();
    user.enterTime= new Date();
    user.page = null;
    user.passedQuiz= false;
    user.exitStatus=null;
    user.quizAttempts= 0;
    user.condition= cond;
    user.avatar= null;
    user.score= 0;
    user.bonus= 0;
    user.lobbyTimeout= LOBBY_TIMEOUT;
    user.gameId= null;
    user.condInfo = {name: cond,
        groupSize: (cond+'GROUPS_SIZE').split('.').reduce((o, i) => o[i], CONDITIONS_SETTINGS),
        bonusConversion: (cond+'BONUS_CONVERSION').split('.').reduce((o, i) => o[i], CONDITIONS_SETTINGS),
        N_ROUNDS: (cond+'N_ROUNDS').split('.').reduce((o, i) => o[i], CONDITIONS_SETTINGS),
    };
    return user;
});
```

Then, from `meteor mongo` I verified that created users do have the new custom fields that I added. Now, in  `imports/api/users/server/publications.js` I have the following snippet:

```
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor'
Meteor.publish('users.user', function(currentUser) {
    let user=  Meteor.users.find({_id:currentUser}, {
        fields: {
            _id: 1,
            enterTime: 1,
            page: 1,
            passedQuiz: 1,
            exitStatus: 1,
            quizAttempts:1,
            condition:1,
            avatar: 1,
            score:1,
            bonus: 1,
            lobbyTimeout: 1,
            gameId: 1,
            conditionInfo: 1
        }
    });
    if ( user ) {
        return user;
    }
    return this.ready();
});
```

Also, in my `imports/startup/client/index.js` I have the subscription:

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
    Meteor.subscribe('users.user');
});
```

However, on the client side, `console.log(Meteor.user())` only shows the `_id` and `username` without any of my custom fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't pass in the `currentUser` parameter from the client in your `subscribe`. However that's a strict no-no since the client is not trusted (someone could easily send a different user's `_id` to your method). Rewrite your publication as:

```
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor'
Meteor.publish('users.user', function() {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, {
      fields: {
        _id: 1,
        enterTime: 1,
        page: 1,
        passedQuiz: 1,
        exitStatus: 1,
        quizAttempts:1,
        condition:1,
        avatar: 1,
        score:1,
        bonus: 1,
        lobbyTimeout: 1,
        gameId: 1,
        conditionInfo: 1
      }
    });
  }
  return this.ready();
});
```

Comment: Ok this fixes it